# Parse Json Embeded in Page

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following object in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var caseMgtData =
{
"totalNumOfCase": 2,
"cases": [{
    "id": "50017000003fWF4AAM",
    "caseNumber": "00007764",
    "status": "New",
    "priority": "Low",
    "subject": "Issue summary goes here",
    "description": "Full Description Goes here",
    "caseOwner": "00Go00000018IpCEAU",
    "contact": {
        "recordId": "00317000005XJUCAA4",
        "name": "blah Herring",
        "firstName": "blah",
        "lastName": "blah",
        "email": "blah@blah.com.x",
        "phone": "5209012560",
        "mobile": "5204655312"
    },
    "timeOpened": "2016-02-22T05:12:16.000+0000",
    "caseOrigin": "Web"
}, {
    "id": "50017000001NVoyAAG",
    "caseNumber": "00002009",
    "status": "Closed",
    "priority": "Low",
    "subject": "blah last test",
    "description": "blah last test",
    "caseOwner": "00517000000YfBJAA0",
    "contact": {
        "recordId": "00317000005XJUCAA4",
        "name": "Blah blah",
        "firstName": "blah",
        "lastName": "Herring",
        "email": "blah@blah.com.x",
        "phone": "5209012560",
        "mobile": "5204655312"
    },
    "timeOpened": "2015-03-10T17:34:36.000+0000",
    "timeClosed": "2015-06-03T05:37:16.000+0000",
    "caseOrigin": "Web"
}]
}
</script>
```

How can I use jQuery to display each case?  I can get caseMgtData.cases[0].status and show just that but How can I do an each or foreach and display the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a global javascript object, not JSON, so you can manipulate it how ever you would with JS normally

```js
for (var i = 0; i < caseMgtData.cases.length; i++) {
  console.log(caseMgtData.cases[i].subject);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">var caseMgtData =
{
"totalNumOfCase": 2,
"cases": [{
    "id": "50017000003fWF4AAM",
    "caseNumber": "00007764",
    "status": "New",
    "priority": "Low",
    "subject": "Issue summary goes here",
    "description": "Full Description Goes here",
    "caseOwner": "00Go00000018IpCEAU",
    "contact": {
        "recordId": "00317000005XJUCAA4",
        "name": "blah Herring",
        "firstName": "blah",
        "lastName": "blah",
        "email": "blah@blah.com.x",
        "phone": "5209012560",
        "mobile": "5204655312"
    },
    "timeOpened": "2016-02-22T05:12:16.000+0000",
    "caseOrigin": "Web"
}, {
    "id": "50017000001NVoyAAG",
    "caseNumber": "00002009",
    "status": "Closed",
    "priority": "Low",
    "subject": "blah last test",
    "description": "blah last test",
    "caseOwner": "00517000000YfBJAA0",
    "contact": {
        "recordId": "00317000005XJUCAA4",
        "name": "Blah blah",
        "firstName": "blah",
        "lastName": "Herring",
        "email": "blah@blah.com.x",
        "phone": "5209012560",
        "mobile": "5204655312"
    },
    "timeOpened": "2015-03-10T17:34:36.000+0000",
    "timeClosed": "2015-06-03T05:37:16.000+0000",
    "caseOrigin": "Web"
}]
}
</script>

<body></body>
```